# select a subset of nsmanagedobject using filterpredicate in coredata

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

There is a project with a Coredata datamodel. Each class has a relationship with Type. Type contains an attribute 'content', amongst other attrs.

It could be modelled with relationships as such

```
Element
  dimensions
  colors
  ...

Colors
    type----->ColorType
                content

Dimension
   quantity
   unit
   type ----->DimensionType
               content
Unit
   type ----->UnitType
               content

...

ObjectX
   type ----->TypeX
               content
```

Rather than having many Types, I prefer the following

```
Super
 type -----> Type
              content


Unit isa Super
Dimension isa Super
...
ObjectX isa Super
```

It seems straightforward to retrieve a subset of nsmanagedobjects whereby an attribute contains a matched string, such as an attribute ownersClassname by way of a FilterPredicate.

```
Super
 type -----> Type
              content
              ownersClassName
```

DimensionType might be 'length', 'width', 'height'
ColorType might be 'hex', 'rgb', cymk'
UnitType might be 'mm', 'cm', 'inch', etc.

Element may have one to many dimensions, colors, etc. And the user shouldn't need to type 'mm', 'rgb' so the need for specific dropdowns setters. And there is a need to be flexible to forecast changes in models that would otherwise destroy the DBMS.

The problem:

How can one set this ownersClassName string to 'Unit', 'Dimension', 'Color' when a user adds a new Type, such that the FilterPredicate can filter in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

You set default object values for relationships during `awakeFromInsert` of your model class.

You can cache the default values so you aren't refetching the object from the store on every insert.